# php preg_replace returns unknown modifier '+'?

Tags: php, regex

trying to fix this regex. Its supposed to find any hyperlinks in a string and put anchor tags around them.  Keeps coming back, unkown identifier '+'.  I thought the plus sing was part of regex?

```
<?php

//replace links with clickable links

// match protocol://address/path/
$comments = preg_replace("[a-zA-Z]+://([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*", "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $comments);

// match www.something
$comments = preg_replace("(^| )(www([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*)", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\">\\2</a>", $comments);

?>
```

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

A PCRE patterns (that's what you give to `preg_replace`) needs to be enclosed by [delimiters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

```
~[a-zA-Z]+://([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*~
```

Here the `~` are the delimiters. I used this char because it doesn't occur in the rest of the regex.

To explain the error: PCRE thinks that `[` is the delimiter (as the first char always is the delimiter). So when it find the corresponding closing delimiter `]` is considers everything after it a modifier. And as there is no `+` modifier you get an error ;)

Comment: Thank you sir. an I thought regular regex was hard enough, now I have to grok PCRE, lol

Comment: If you actually use the ~, you can escape it with \~ in the regex. If the regex is built dynamically, you can use preg_quote. The delimiter is what you want, I generally use /, ~ or #, depending on the regular expression.

Comment: do I put the tildes around the 'replace' part too? (the 2nd arg?)

Comment: im not getting any errors now, but the anchor tags aren't being added

Answer (score -1):

try replacing

```
"[a-zA-Z]+://([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*", "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>"
```

with

```
r'[a-zA-Z]+://([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*', '<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>'
```

Comment: That'd be a syntax error: PHP doens't have a regex literal.